# Heater and its current limiting

Tags: voltage, resistance, heat

I'm having a hard time with a hobby scheme for a mini heater. The heater is 5 V, but I'm planning to run it at 6 V soon. The heater has 3 Ω resistance (they are 2 in parallel each ~6 Ω). I do limit the voltage with 2 SS34 diodes to get it close to 5 V for the future 6 V supply.
Now... to limit the current I'm using eight 100 Ω resistors, that total makes 12.5 Ω when in parallel. I want to turn off/on the heater with a MOSFET, for educational purposes. The MOSFET gate is pulled down by 68K to ensure a known state, and its charging speed is limited by 100R.

My problem is that the heater does not heat, it has only 0.65 V across itself. I have switched the places of the heater and the resistors, but nothing changed.

If I add more resistors in parallel to the R19, that will raise the voltage across the heater, but will increase the current. I'm lost. How can I limit the current to say, 500 Ω for 5 V? At the moment I have 0.25 A current flow, but the resistors heat up, not the heater.

Please help. Schematic:

[image: schema]

Comment: 1. All resistors are heaters, and all heaters are resistors. The observation that your resistors heat up when you push current through them should not surprise you. 2. You don't get to set both the voltage across & the current through a fixed resistance at the same time. You either apply a voltage across the resistor, and the current is then determined as I = V/R, or you force a current through the resistor and the voltage is determined as V = IR. You can't choose the numbers to plug in to all 3 variables at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I had to connect the two mini heaters in series, to get ~12 Ohm, and for 5V now I have ~450 mA! Problem solved. No resistors needed at all.

Comment: if the resistance of each heater is 3 Ω, then how do you figure that the overall resistance is 12 Ω when two are connected in series?

Comment: I have 2 in parallel (written up), making "as one" 3 Ω. The resistance halves from 6 Ω to 3 Ω, in parallel. When connected in series its 6 Ω + 6 Ω = 12 Ω. Lucky, because for 6 V I get exactly 500 mA, as I wanted.